# Youtube HTTP Request

Tags: c#, youtube, httprequest, youtube-data-api

I want to get captions from youtube videos and I have seen that it's easy to do with video that have been subbed by humans with an HTTP request as following:

```
https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=[LINK]&lang=en
```

The problem emerges when I try to do it with auto generated subtitle because it gives me a blank page.

I tried going to the network tab of chrome to find out what kind of HTTP request the browser does, and I found out that it uses the same link but with more specific parameters that change in every youtube video:

**Signature**: Two Hexadecimal numbers separated by a dot with length 40 each 
**Expire** : A decimal number with length 10

The other parameters are equals, so I need to figure out how to get them. I can't find any API that helps me with this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well why do you want to inspect network calls and figure it out from there. I think Google transits data with protobuf, so good luck trying to decrypt the params.

Why not use their official api and do it the correct and legal way ?

What you want is captions.
Here's the documentation on its api:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions

You, probably, will want to first call the 'list' method to get a list of all the available caption tracks for the video. Then the 'download' method to fetch the captions.

The aforementioned link to the docs also includes code examples you will need.

Another Way to do it would be:

1) Call http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=videoID

2) Parse the response as a query string (URL Encoded String)

3) Convert the string to an array/object

4) The Url to fetch caption tracks  (Including the auto-generated ones) will be present in "player_response" property.

Comment: As I wrote, getting normal subtitles already work, the problem is when nobody wrote them and they are auto generated by YouTube, I want the auto generated one

Comment: The api should give you the auto-generated transcript, but anyhow let me add another method which I use when the api doesn't fulfil my needs

Comment: @Andreawu98 Added another way to do it. Tried and tested just now